# Correctly override Grandparent method, already implemented in Parent method

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding, decorator

Edit: It appears that my problem is coming from somewhere else entirely. If you haven't read the rest of this topic yet, I have a `class A`, a `class B` extending `class A`, and a `class BDecorator` extending `class B`.
I thought I couldn't override a specific function from `class B` within my decorator, but after days of testing and trials it seems my issue lies with the way I am creating threads.
`class A` implements Runnable, and has a function `listen()` creating the thread and calling `start()`.
I create the thread with the argument `this`. This is important because at the specific time the thread is created, `this` will be of type `class B`.

```java
new BDecorator(new B());
//             ^ The thread is created with the creation of this object, before it can be passed as an argument to BDecorator
```

Since the thread is of `class B`, it will call the `foo()` of the `B object` used for creating it.

While I wouldn't say that this issue is solved, it is now an entirely different problem and has nothing to do with polymorphism. Thank you
@akuzminykh, @dreamcrash and @Itay Dumay for helping me try solving this issue, as well as correctly formatting this post.

---

I have an abstract `class A`, implementing Runnable. `A` does the following in the `run()` method (shortened):

```java
final public void run() {
    try {
        this.foo(message);
    }
    //...
}
```

`Class A` also has the following function:

```java
protected abstract void foo(String message);
```

**First iteration of the decorator: Overriding the foo function.**

I have then created a class B, which isn't abstract, doing this:

```java
public class B extends A {
    // Constructors and getters/setters go here
    
    protected void foo(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

This code works fine. I have since decided to add functionalities to `B` that wouldn't change the way the whole app works, by creating a decorator.

```java
public class BDecorator extends B {
    B decoratedB;
    
    public BDecorator(B b) {
        this.decoratedB = b;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void foo(String message) {
        this.decoratedB.foo("Testing a foo decorator: " + message);
    }
}
```

To make things short, I'm trying to override a method from a parent, that was already implementing said method from their own parent (grandchild overring method from parent, implementing method from grandparent).

**Second iteration of the decorator: Overriding a new bar function created in `B`.**

What's weird is that I also have a method written in `B` like so:

```java
public class B extends A {
    // Constructors and getters/setters go here

    protected void foo(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    protected void bar(String message) {
      System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

`bar` doesn't exist anywhere in `class A`.
I can confirm that the program will actually call `BDecorator::bar()` with the following override (when I place breakpoints):

```java
public class BDecorator extends B {
    B decoratedB;
    
    public BDecorator(B b) {
        this.decoratedB = b;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void foo(String message) {
        this.decoratedB.foo("Testing a foo decorator: " + message);
    }

    // This method wasn't in A. It was only present in B, and for some reasons it gets called.
    @Override
    protected void bar(String message) {
        this.decoratedB.bar("Testing a bar decorator: " + message);
    }
}
```

Here's what happens in my main:

```java
B firstTestSubject = new BDecorator(new B(...));
BDecorator secondTestSubject = new BDecorator(new B(...));

// Let's test both foo functions
firstTestSubject.foo("Hello world!");
secondTestSubject.foo("Hello world!");

// Now let's test both bar functions
firstTestSubject.bar("Goodbye world!");
secondTestSubject.bar("Goodbye world!)";
```

Output:

```
> Hello world!
> Hello world!
> Testing a bar decorator: Goodbye world!
> Testing a bar decorator: Goodbye world!
```

The question is: Why is the `foo override` from `BDecorator` never called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is: Why is the `foo` override from BDecorator never called?

It is called:

From the `BDecorator` class, add the following `Statement`:

```
@Override
protected void foo(String message) {
    System.out.println("Do I even exist?");
    this.decoratedB.foo("Testing a foo decorator: " + message);
}
```

the output:

```
Do I even exist?
Testing a foo decorator: Hello world!
Do I even exist?
Testing a foo decorator: Hello world!
Testing a bar decorator: Goodbye world!
Testing a bar decorator: Goodbye world!
```

The foo method from the `BDecorator` class is called, and then forwards the call to the `foo` `method` from B passed on the constructor of the `BDecorator` in your case:

```
new BDecorator(new B(...));
```

and instance object from the class `B`.